# In the category of sets, why are singleton sets terminal?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I'm trying to understand why the category of sets is defined the way it is, with singleton sets as terminal objects. If the "Set" category contains all of the possible sets, and all of the possible morphisms between those sets, why wouldn't there be injective, non-surjective morphisms from the singleton sets to all other sets with infinite cardinality? In this case, there wouldn't be any terminal objects.

So what is the rule that leads it to being defined the way it is defined, rather than being defined with infinite sets and morphisms. I guess that it has something to do with it being a "concrete" category. But I don't see how it's so obvious.

Comment: this belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm having a really hard time following this question. It sounds like your definitions are mixed up, but I can't tell exactly how. When you ask on math. stackexchange I suggest including the specific definitions you are asking about, including the definition of terminal object.

Comment: https://byorgey.wordpress.com/catsters-guide-2/#terminal-and-initial-objects and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets

Comment: sorry about not putting it on maths.stackexchange.com that's actually where I wanted it to go!

Comment: This question belongs to Math.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A terminal object in a category by definition is an object T with the property that for any object C in the category, there is exactly one arrow C -> T.  In the category of sets, a singleton object, for example {1} has this property:

> For any set S there is a function f:S -> {1} defined by setting f(s)=1
>   for any element s of S. There can't be another function g:S -> {1},
>   because for some element s of S, g(s) would have to be an element t of
>   {1} other than 1, but there is no such element t.  So there is exactly
>   one function from S to {1} for each object S of the category.

Your remark about there being many functions from {1} to a set S is irrelevant; they go in the wrong direction to be relevant to the definition of terminal object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it is about having exactly one arrow, and that we can ignore other arrows if there are more than one. If we look at a set S with |S| = 3 say, with a function f:S->{1, 2}, defined by setting the f(s_1) = 1 and f(s_2) = 2 and discarding s_3, even if we have another function g:S->{1, 2}, defined by setting g(s_2)=1 and g(s_3)=2 and discarding s_1, wouldn't f be equivalent to g? How would they not be considered the same arrow?

Comment: Looking at the definition for equality of functions in sets. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s996-category-theory-for-scientists-spring-2013/textbook/MIT18_S996S13_chapter2.pdf Page 18. "Note that two functions f, g : X -> Y are equal if and only if for every element x in X f(x) = g(x)", so it breaks equality. Now I have to see why equality is defined like that

Comment: ok, so have gone back and learnt functions in set theory :-). I was getting confused thinking that relations could be functions. Functions are defined as having only one f(x) for each x. So if f(x) is a singleton x cannot be anything other than x (and therefore only one function). Thanks guys

Comment: But why empty set is not terminal object?